# как в каждый scss файл записать строчку @import "mixins"

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

В файл `index.js` подключается файл `mixins.scss` и `index.scss`. В `mixins.scss` такой код:

```
@mixin colorRed {
   color: red;
}
```

в `index.scss` такой код:

```
body {
   @include colorRed;
}
```

есть такой `webpack.config.js`:

```
            {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
            ]
        }
```

Компилиться с ошибкой, что объявлен неизвестный миксин colorRed в `index.scss`:

```
    SassError: Undefined mixin.
  ╷
3 │     @include colorRed;
  │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

Логично, ведь в `index.scss` я не прописал импорт `mixins.scss`, но это тупо: отдельно прописывать в каждый файл стилей @import 'mixins', ведь я планирую использовать компонентную структуру, значит, подключать всегда придется так:

`@import '../../../../../../../../mixins`

но это маразм, особенно если потом компоненты будут менять свою иерархию.
Я вычтал, что можно просто в каждый файл стилей через `webpack` динамически вставлять что-нибудь, например, заветную строчку @import 'mixins', но как это сделать я хз. Пробовла что-то такое, но не выходит:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        sassOptions: {
                            additionalData: '@import "mixins"',
                            includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

ичпользую последние версии `webpack` `sass` `node.js`

Comment: переделал вопрос, уточнил некоторые моменты

Comment: компилиться без ошибки, но не решает проблему

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#object - это пробовали?

Comment: пробовал - не работает, но я подозреваю, что как-то неправильно делаю.
includePaths: ['@import "N:\react_t\webpack-test-6\src\mixins.scss"']

Comment: уберите `@import`

Comment: так тоже пробовал - не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, нашел я решение проблемы.

1. Скачиваем это https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-append
2. в шапке конфига пишем `const libImport = '@import "./mixins";'` (оригинал https://github.com/dumconstantin/webpack-append/issues/2#issuecomment-254129710)
3. Чуть меням сборку:

   ```
    module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.sсss$/i,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
                'webpack-append?'+ libImport
            ]
        }
    ]}
   ```
4. Убираем из `index.js` импорт `mixins.scss`

Ну и пошла жара, как говорится: создаешь сколько угодно компонентов, влкадываешь их куда угодно и все миксины прекрасно объявляются в scss файлах, компилятся и работают.